# Line and curve intersection in python using bezier curve and vertical line

Tags: python, curve, bezier

I have a Bezier curve and am trying to intersect it with a vertical line. I don't have a background in maths so I was hoping to find the point of intersection using an intersection function without having to solve line equations. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import cbook

from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

verts = [
    (0., 0.),  # P0
    (0, 100), # P1
    (100, 0), # P2
    (100, 100), # P3
    ]

codes = [Path.MOVETO,
         Path.CURVE4,
         Path.CURVE4,
         Path.CURVE4,
         ]

path = Path(verts, codes)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='none', lw=2, picker=0)

#add the line
ax.add_patch(patch)

xs, ys = zip(*verts)
#add the handles lines
#ax.plot(xs, ys, 'x--', lw=2, color='black', ms=10)

#ax.text(1, 1, 'P0')
#ax.text(20, 4, 'P1')
#ax.text(96, 80, 'P2')
#ax.text(96, 96, 'P3')

ax.set_xlim(-0.1, 100.1)
ax.set_ylim(-0.1, 100.1)

intervals = float(5)
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=intervals)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.grid(True,'both')

#################

print ""
#print zip(*path.iter_segments(stroke_width=10.0,curves=False))

def on_move(event):
    #thisline = event.artist
    xmouse, ymouse = event.xdata, event.ydata
    #print "x: ", str(xmouse), ", y: ", str(ymouse)

def on_click(event):
    xmouse, ymouse = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print xmouse
    newline = Line2D([xmouse,xmouse], [0,100])
    ax.add_line(newline)
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)

###############

plt.show()
```

[image: here is the graph]

Comment: But why not just solve the equation anyway? Just because you don't have a background in it doesn't mean there aren't plenty of websites that explain how to do this. For cubic curves, you'd be implementing "Cardano's algorithm", explained in a few places on a the web. You solve it separately for each dimension, then see which solutions are found in not just one but both, and those are your answers.

Comment: I know this doesn't solve the problem but to calculate these types of lines... Note to self: 
An odd degree polynomial will create an inverted s-curve as shown in the image. For example y=x^3, y=x^5, y=x^7. There are two kinds of translations that we can do to a graph of a function. They are shifting and scaling. This can be done using a formula. 'a' is the vertical scale, 'b' is the horizontal scale, 'c' is the vertical shift, 'd' is the horizontal shift. y = a * ( b (x-c) )+ d for example this should produce a similar graph to the image in the original post: y=0.1415*(0.1415*(x-50))^3+50

Comment: No it won't: while It *can* exhibit an S curve, the rule you stated only holds for a true polynomial - something that Bezier curves are not. First, they're not simple polynomial functions but a *parametric functions* with a polynomial basis, so there is no guarantee that the behaviour in a single dimension carries over to two or more. Additionally, Bezier curves don't even use full polynomials but *sections* of polynomial, so even in one dimension they do not need to obey the same overall shape rule at all. See http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#extended

Answer (score 1):

Just use cubic root finding anyway. You don't need a background in math, all you need is to have someone that already did this for you, which there are. You want a python implementation of cubic root finding, but what you really want is *any* implmentation of cubic root finding for Bezier curves that can be adapted to Python, so I'm going to give you a JavaScript implementation and it should be almost trivial to adapt that to python.

First, we rotate the Bezier curve and line both such that the line becomes the x-axis. We do this, because we can then treat "intersection finding" as simply "root finding" (let's do this in pseudocode):

```
pts = line.points + curve.points
offset = pts[0];
for all p in pts:
  p -= offset
angle = atan2(pts[1].y, pts[0].x)
for all p in pts:
  p = rotate(p, -angle)
```

done.

When expressed in terms of interpolation parameter (the Bezier curve control variable `t` in this case), intersections are invariant to linear transforms, so that's handy.

We then use Cardano's algorithm to do cubic root finding, which I explain over on http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#extremities, and the code for which is based on http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/polynomials/cubicAlgebra.htm:

```
function getCubicRoots(pa, pb, pc, pd) {
  // pa...pd are our cubic bezier coordinates in one dimension
  var d = (-pa + 3*pb - 3*pc + pd),
      a = (3*pa - 6*pb + 3*pc) / d,
      b = (-3*pa + 3*pb) / d,
      c = pa / d;

  var p = (3*b - a*a)/3,
      p3 = p/3,
      q = (2*a*a*a - 9*a*b + 27*c)/27,
      q2 = q/2,
      discriminant = q2*q2 + p3*p3*p3;

  // and some variables we're going to use later on:
  var u1,v1,root1,root2,root3;

  // three possible real roots:
  if (discriminant < 0) {
    var mp3  = -p/3,
        mp33 = mp3*mp3*mp3,
        r    = sqrt( mp33 ),
        t    = -q / (2*r),
        cosphi = t<-1 ? -1 : t>1 ? 1 : t,
        phi  = acos(cosphi),
        crtr = cuberoot(r),
        t1   = 2*crtr;
    root1 = t1 * cos(phi/3) - a/3;
    root2 = t1 * cos((phi+2*pi)/3) - a/3;
    root3 = t1 * cos((phi+4*pi)/3) - a/3;
    return [root1, root2, root3].filter(accept);
  }

  // three real roots, but two of them are equal:
  else if(discriminant === 0) {
    u1 = q2 < 0 ? cuberoot(-q2) : -cuberoot(q2);
    root1 = 2*u1 - a/3;
    root2 = -u1 - a/3;
    return [root1, root2].filter(accept);
  }

  // one real root, two complex roots
  else {
    var sd = sqrt(discriminant);
    u1 = cuberoot(sd - q2);
    v1 = cuberoot(sd + q2);
    root1 = u1 - v1 - a/3;
    return [root1].filter(accept);
  }
}
```

You compute the roots for your `x` and `y` functions separately, which will give you two lists of `t` values for which there *might* be intersections, and any `t` value that appears in both `x` and `y` lists *is* an intersection.

This code relies on two helper functions, which are pretty trivial but in the code I copied are of the form:

```
// A helper function to filter for values in the [0,1] interval:
function accept(t) {
  return 0<=t && t <=1;
}

// A real-cuberoots-only function:
function crt(v) {
  if(v<0) return -Math.pow(-v,1/3);
  return Math.pow(v,1/3);
}
```